# Powershell Variable for dynamic Move-Item

Tags: powershell

I have a function that looks at some registry settings for SQL Server which just pulls put the data and log location and puts them in variables. But I run into an issue when I pass them into `Move-Item`. Basically:

```
fnGetDataNLog
```

Returns `$datalocation, $loglocation`

When I run `Move-Item -Path $datalocaton -Destination $loglocation` I get

Cannot bind argument to parameter `'path'` because it does not exist.

Is that due to its passing a runtime variable? Is there another way to do that then.

Comment: What is assigned to the `$datalocaton` variable? It should be a file/folder path.

Comment: Hi Drew, Yes it is a unc path

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `Test-Path` to ensure the location exists.

If you `$Datalocation` is a UNC path to a directory you can do the below. eg. `$Datalocation = '\\UNC\Path\To\Folder'`

```
If(-not (Test-Path -Path $Datalocation)) {
    New-Item -Path $Datalocation -ItemType Directory
}
Move-Item -Path $Datalocation-Destination $loglocation
```

This will test if the path at `$Datalocation` exists, if `-not` then it will create it.

if the UNC path is a string that goes to a file, ie. not an object result from a `Get-ChildItem`, then you can use a bit of regex to get the parent folder and then do the below. The regex will remove everything after the last `\`.
eg. `\\UNC\Path\To\Folder\File.txt` becomes `\\UNC\Path\To\Folder\`

```
If(-not (Test-Path -Path ($Datalocation -replace '[^\\]+$'))) {
    New-Item -Path $Datalocation -ItemType Directory
}
Move-Item -Path $Datalocation -Destination $loglocation
```